# Multiple og meta tags on one page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, fragment-identifier

I have a single page for articles on my website `example.com/articles`.
Each article has an anchor tag, therefore a particular URL scrolls to the specific articles:
`example.com/articles#article1`, `example.com/articles#article2` and so on.

I want to be able to share each article on Facebook, with its own meta properties (`og:url`, `og:title`, `og:type`, `og:description`, `og:image`).

From what I found, Facebook only crawls the page for one set of tags (for the canonical URL), but is it possible to implement a script for crawling specific metadata for each `#article` URL?

Comment: No, that is not possible, because the hash is a mere client-side construct, and does not even get send to the server on an HTTP request. Basically you will need one actual unique URL for each unique combination of OG meta data you want to share.

Comment: Any chance to create these URLs without having to move articles on new pages?

Comment: You will have to set up a basic HTML document with the relevant OG meta data under those URLs; you can redirect human visitors elsewhere with a little JS snippet.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I created new html pages for each article with only basic structure and added the meta tags in the head, and also set-up a redirect like this <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://www.example.com/articles#article1'" />

Comment: I was expecting a much easier and slicky way to do it, but I am happy with this at the moment.

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible with such redirections. Thank you for confirmation. I might implement that too.